# Can't do any modifications on NTFS disks

Tags: ntfs

I have some NTFS volumes when I used to have a dual boot machine (windows10 and Ubuntu 20.04). Now I only have Ubuntu but these NTFS volumes don't let me crate, delete or copy any files into them. Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: It's a consequence of Windows' Fast Startup feature. If you no longer have Windows then the best you can do is to backup anything you need from those partitions and format them with a proper file system for Ubuntu. No Linux desktop have tools to error correct NTFS if it becomes corrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu will mount ntfs file partitions as read only if they are not clean, i.e., if the file system is not in a consistent state.

ntfs is a proprietary file system. Therefore, ntfs file systems should best be checked on a Windows system. Although Linux has the `ntfsfix` tool, it allows for relatively basic repairs only.

If you do not anymore have Windows, then it is strongly recommended to reformat the drives to `ext4` or another file system that is fully supported under linux. Keep ntfs around only if you intend to use it sometimes with Windows or for non critical uses (e.g. a TV that only reads ntfs format, if the file system is broken, you just reformat).